Extract SVG Elements and Title from HTML using BeautifulSoup
I have a chunk of html I have extracted using BeautifulSoup which containts an SVG path and a title.
I am wondering if there is a way to extract the title text and the coordinates from this chunk.
<g class="myclass"><title>mytitle</title><path d="M -5, 0 a 5,5 0 1,0 10,0 a 5,5 0 1,0 -10,0" fill="rgba(255,255,255, 0.1" stroke="rgba(10, 158, 117, 0.8)" stroke-width="3" transform="translate(178.00000000000003, 201)"></path></g>
Below is the function which returns the above chunk (rows)
def scrape_spatial_data(page):
    html = page.inner_html("body")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    rows = soup.select("g.myclass")
    return rows

Is there a cleaner way of extracting this using BeautifulSoup?

What is page ? Also, if the website is public, please share its URL and the code you're using to access it

@SIGHUP page is a playwright object. The URL I can't share as it is private. browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False)
context = browser.new_context()
page = context.new_page()
page.goto(the_url)

What output are you expecting exactly? By "coordinates" do you mean the values in translate(), or the d= value?

A reasonable approach to this would be to return a dictionary that is keyed on the attribute names (from the path tag) and the title.
I recommend using lxml (if available) as the HTML parser for enhanced performance.
Try this:
from playwright.sync_api import Page
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
from functools import cache

@cache
def get_parser():
    try:
        import lxml
        return "lxml"
    except Exception:
        pass
    return "html.parser"

def scrape_spatial_data(page: Page) -> dict[str, str]:
    html = page.inner_html("body")
    soup = BS(html, get_parser())
    result = {}
    if row := soup.select_one("g.myclass"):
        if t := row.select_one("title"):
            result["title"] = t.text
        if p := row.select_one("path"):
            result.update(p.attrs)
    return result

For the data shown in the question this would reveal:
{
  "title": "mytitle",
  "d": "M -5, 0 a 5,5 0 1,0 10,0 a 5,5 0 1,0 -10,0",
  "fill": "rgba(255,255,255, 0.1",
  "stroke": "rgba(10, 158, 117, 0.8)",
  "stroke-width": "3",
  "transform": "translate(178.00000000000003, 201)"
}


Playwright already has a powerful location API that auto-waits and works on the live page. Snapshotting the page HTML over to BeautifulSoup just to do a selection seems unnecessary, like buying a bike just to push it around instead of riding it. On the other hand, if OP's HTML can be requested statically, I would not use Playwright, and instead use requests to fetch the page HTML without browser automation.

@ggorlen Fair comment but bear in mind what the question is. BeautifulSoup may well not be appropriate but that's (apparently) what's required. Ours is not to reason why

People ask XY problems all the time, and it's a disservice to future visitors as well as OP not to at least mention that there might be a better way to doing whatever it is they want to achieve. In any case, if the question is about BS, then Playwright seems extra--one or the other is--I've been using both technologies for years and have never seen a use case for combining them. It's usually done by beginners who aren't familiar with the libraries.

@ggorlen 100%, I am indeed a beginner with both libraries - the table which I am scraping data from has a 'next page' button which I use playwright to navigate and then BS to snapshot that data. If there is a way to do the same in Playwright without using BS I would be keen to learn

If you're using Playwright, there's no need to use BeautifulSoup as well--dumping the live DOM to a string just to feed into BS is an antipattern and prone to error. Playwright has a full suite of locators and selectors that work on the live DOM and even auto-wait for actionability before operation.
So, assuming you're automating a single page app, save yourself the dependency, extra syntax, performance hit, and potential bugs, and stick to locators throughout:
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright # 1.44.0


svg = """<Your example SVG from the question, verbatim>"""


with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch()
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.set_content(svg) # for demonstration, normally use goto
    title = page.locator(".myclass title").text_content()
    coordinates = page.locator(".myclass path").get_attribute("transform")
    print(title, coordinates)
    browser.close()

If you want to extract the values from the translate() arguments, you can use:
x, y = [float(x) for x in re.findall(r"[\d.]+", coordinates)]

If you want all attributes from the path element, you can use JS in the browser natively:
attrs = page.locator(".myclass path").evaluate("""
    el => Object.fromEntries([...el.attributes].map(e => [e.name, e.value]))
""")

On the other hand, if you're scraping a static HTML page, consider dropping Playwright in favor of requests + BeautifulSoup.

Thanks - will try this out. Wanting to get best performance possible so this will be useful. The page is a dynamic html page so will need Playwright I think
